# Configuring Lists for use with Azure LUIS

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding

I am using microsoft LUIS in my application.

I am configuring the intents and entities. When I set up the intents I can select works and mark them as entities. These create simple entities.

Simple entities cannot have Canonical Form and Synonyms as far as I can see and I cannot use any list entities I create in the intents screen.

How do I set an entities to be a list and link them to intents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create/add non-simple entities you need to create them via the Entities view. This view is accessible by clicking on **Entities** in the Sidebar menu:

[image: Screencap of Sidebar]

**[Documentation on Adding List Entities to LUIS App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/add-entities#list-entities)**